# Angular 2 viewchild not working - cannot read property nativeElement of undefined

Tags: angular

I have this component called multiselect.component and I access one of its html elements `(<select id="category-select">)` in the .ts file.

multiselect.component.html:

```
<select id="category-select" multiple class="form-control">
    <option value="1">Meat</option>
    <option value="2">Dairy</option>
    <option value="3">Confectionary</option>
    <option value="4">Dessert</option>
    <option value="7">Baking</option>
    <option value="6">Grocers</option>
    <option value="5">Restaurants</option>
    <option value="8">Condiments</option>
    <option value="9">beverages</option>
</select>
<div class="form-control-icon" id="keywords-icon"></div>
```

multiselect.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'multiselect',
    templateUrl: 'app/shared/multiselect.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ 'app/shared/multiselect.component.css' ]
})
export class MultiselectComponent implements OnInit {
    items = 'one two three'.split(' ');
    selectedCategories;
    allSelected;
    numberOfCategories = 9;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.selectedCategories = [];
        (<any>$("#category-select")).multiselect({
            buttonWidth: '100%',
            buttonContainer: '<div style="height: 34px;" />',
            buttonClass: 'none',
            nonSelectedText: "select categories",
            nSelectedText: ' categories',
            allSelectedText: "all categories",
            selectAllNumber: false,
            includeSelectAllOption: true,
            disableIfEmpty: true,
            onSelectAll: () => {
                this.allSelected = true;
            },
            onInitialized: () => {

            },
            onChange: (option, checked) => {
                this.changed();
            }
        });
    }

    changed() {
        this.selectedCategories = [];
        var self = this;

        $('#category-select option:selected').each(function () {
            self.selectedCategories.push(
                <any>($(this).text(), $(this).val())
            )
        });
        console.log(this.selectedCategories);
        if (this.selectedCategories.length < this.numberOfCategories) {
            this.allSelected = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I think that the way I access it is bad practice by using jquery. I think it can be accessed with @viewChild instead.

So I'm trying to change it like this (I am first just getting rid of the first jquery element accessor then will do the rest later):

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'multiselect',
    templateUrl: 'app/shared/multiselect.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ 'app/shared/multiselect.component.css' ]
})
export class MultiselectComponent implements OnInit {
    items = 'one two three'.split(' ');
    selectedCategories;
    allSelected;
    numberOfCategories = 9;

    @ViewChild('category-select') select;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.selectedCategories = [];
        this.select.nativeElement.multiselect({
            buttonWidth: '100%',
            buttonContainer: '<div style="height: 34px;" />',
            buttonClass: 'none',
            nonSelectedText: "select categories",
            nSelectedText: ' categories',
            allSelectedText: "all categories",
            selectAllNumber: false,
            includeSelectAllOption: true,
            disableIfEmpty: true,
            onSelectAll: () => {
                this.allSelected = true;
            },
            onInitialized: () => {

            },
            onChange: (option, checked) => {
                this.changed();
            }
        });
    }

    changed() {
        this.selectedCategories = [];
        var self = this;

        $('#category-select option:selected').each(function () {
            self.selectedCategories.push(
                <any>($(this).text(), $(this).val())
            )
        });
        console.log(this.selectedCategories);
        if (this.selectedCategories.length < this.numberOfCategories) {
            this.allSelected = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting this console error:

```
> EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): EXCEPTION: Error in app/find-page/find-form.component.html:0:56
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
    at MultiselectComponent.System.register.context_1.execute.MultiselectComponent.ngOnInit (http://localhost:3000/js/app/shared/Multiselect.component.js:29:32)
    at DebugAppView._View_FindFormComponent0.detectChangesInternal (FindFormComponent.ngfactory.js:761:90)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:12586:18)
    at DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:12691:48)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectViewChildrenChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:12612:23)
    at DebugAppView._View_FindPageComponent0.detectChangesInternal (FindPageComponent.ngfactory.js:41:8)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:12586:18)
    at DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:12691:48)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectViewChildrenChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:12612:23)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChangesInternal (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:12597:18)
ERROR CONTEXT:
[object Object]
```

Why am I getting that error?

**After changing to AfterViewInit, I'm now getting this error:**

```
platform-browser.umd.js:937 Error: Uncaught (in promise): EXCEPTION: Error in app/find-page/find-form.component.html:13:30
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at DebugAppView._View_FindFormComponent0.detectChangesInternal (FindFormComponent.ngfactory.js:890:72)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:12586:18)
    at DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:12691:48)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectViewChildrenChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:12612:23)
    at DebugAppView._View_FindPageComponent0.detectChangesInternal (FindPageComponent.ngfactory.js:41:8)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:12586:18)
    at DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:12691:48)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectViewChildrenChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:12612:23)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChangesInternal (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:12597:18)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:12586:18)
ERROR CONTEXT:
[object Object]
    at resolvePromise (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:538:32)
    at http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:515:14
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:323:29)
    at Object.onInvoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:9245:45)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:322:35)
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:216:44)
    at http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:571:58
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:356:38)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:9236:45)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:355:43)
```

The error seems to be in FindFormComponent.

FindFormComponent is just the form that has the multiselect (a form to fill out which will then find products).

Here is the relevant html from the FindFormComponent that utilises length:

```
<div class="row has-error-text">
    <div class="col-sm-8 offset-sm-2 col-md-6 offset-md-3 col-lg-4 offset-lg-4 input-group btn-group" style="height:64px;">
        <div style="position: relative; display: inline-block; width: 100%;">
            <multiselect #multiselect></multiselect>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row error-text"  [style.display]="multiselect.selectedCategories.length < 1 && submitted ? 'block' : 'none'">
    <div class="col-sm-8 offset-sm-2 col-md-6 offset-md-3 col-lg-4 offset-lg-4 form-group input-group btn-group">
        <small>Please select at least 1 category.</small>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.selectedCategories = [];
    this.select.nativeElement.multiselect({
```

to

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.selectedCategories = [];
    this.select.nativeElement.multiselect({
```

The `nativeElement` isn't available before the view is initialized.

Comment: Thanks. It now has another error. Cannot read property length of undefined. Maybe it's referring to the "length" inside my "changed()" function. So length of my selectedCategries array. I'm not really certain though. I'm going to post the error on the question now.

Comment: I guess not because you just set it to `[]`. Hard to tell. Can you please edit your question and add more details there (exact error message, stack trace)

Comment: The stack trace seems to indicate that the exception is related to a form element but I can't tell what could cause it.

Comment: I guess `.multiselect({...})` is some jQuery specific API and not available on a plain HTML `<select>`.

Comment: Yeah .multiselect({...}) is a plugin called bootstrap multiselect. So maybe I just have to use the bad practice that I started with or somehow import it in an angular 2 style

Comment: I guess you need `$(this.select.nativeElement).multiselect({...`

Comment: Hmm getting the same error with that syntax. If it complicates the issue a lot because it is a plugin, it'd probably be okay to keep it using a jquery selector just for that element.

Comment: Hmm, out of ideas.

Comment: No worries. I just posted a little more info about the error now in case anyone has any ideas.