# Angular 2 @viewchild not working - cannot read property of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-directives

i am building the child component byngFir loop and when the ngselect inside that is selected and teh confirm button is presses from parent component then it should call the child component method but it show call a undefiend error

this is lines in parent component where is making it 
      @ViewChild(DropdownsComponent)
      child : DropdownsComponent
i also tried

```
      @ViewChild('child')
      child : DropdownsComponent
```

and in html

```
   <app-dropdowns #child class="col" [listdata]="item"></app-dropdowns>
```

but it shows error that calling a undefined
and also tried these 
[Angular 2 viewchild not working - cannot read property nativeElement of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39094006/angular-2-viewchild-not-working-cannot-read-property-nativeelement-of-undefine)[i also tried this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34947154/angular-2-viewchild-annotation-returns-undefined)
[also tried this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39094006/angular-2-viewchild-not-working-cannot-read-property-nativeelement-of-undefine)

here is the parent component

```
    import { DropdownsComponent } from '../dropdowns/dropdowns.component';

 import {Component, OnInit, TemplateRef, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
 import {Router, ActivatedRoute, ParamMap} from '@angular/router';
 declare var swal : any;
 import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
 import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
 import {BsModalService} from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
 import {BsModalRef} from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal/bs-modal-ref.service';
 import {ProductsService} from './products.service';



 @Component({
   selector: 'app-products',
  templateUrl: './products.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./products.component.scss'],
 })
 export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {
   public items : Array < String >= []
   public slotitems : Array < String >= []
   today = Date.now();
   public products$
   modalRef : BsModalRef;
   modalRef2 : BsModalRef;
   modalref3 : BsModalRef;
   popupproduct
   modalimage
   modaldata
   productData
   dynamicNgselect
   list
   swtich1 = true
   templated
 @ViewChild(DropdownsComponent)
  child : DropdownsComponent

constructor(private modalService : BsModalService, private route :             
ActivatedRoute, private router : Router, private service : ProductsService)         
 {}

 ngOnInit() {
  this.slotitems = ['8:00 am to 10:00 am', '10:00 am to 12:00 pm', '2:00 am 
 to 4:00 pm', '4:00 am to 6:00 pm']
 this
  .service
  .getposition()
  .subscribe(data => this.products$ = data, err => {
    // Log errors if any
    console.log(err);
    this
      .router
      .navigate(['/OnlineOrder'])

  }, () => {
    if (!this.products$) {
      this
        .router
        .navigate(['/onlineOrder'])
    }
    console.log("Nothing here", this.products$)

  });
this
  .service
  .getposition()
  .subscribe(data => this.popupproduct = data, err => {
    // Log errors if any
    console.log(err);

  }, () => {
    console.log("helloasdasd", this.popupproduct)

  });

 }
 addcart(datacoming : any, template : TemplateRef < any >, template2 : 
 TemplateRef < any >, template3 : TemplateRef < any >) {
 this.productData = null;
 this.list = null;
 this.templated = template3
 let someDate = new Date(this.today);
 var numberOfDaysToAdd = 1;
 for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  var dd = someDate.getDate() + i;
  var mm = someDate.getMonth();
  var y = someDate.getFullYear();

  var someFormattedDate = dd + '-' + mm + '-' + y + '     ₹' + datacoming.opr + '/kg';

  this
    .items
    .push(someFormattedDate);
}

this
  .service
  .setidofproduct(datacoming.i._id);
console.log("jol", datacoming);
this
  .service
  .getproduct()
  .subscribe((data) => this.productData = data, err => console.log(err), () => {

    this
      .modalRef
      .hide();
    this.modalRef2 = this
      .modalService
      .show(template);

    console.log("helloasdasd", this.productData);

  })
this.modalRef = this
  .modalService
  .show(template2);

console.log("here is data", datacoming);
this.modaldata = datacoming;

}
private value : any = {};
public selected(value : any) : void {

this.list = this.productData.meatItem.ma
 this.swtich1 = true 
 console.log('Selected value is: ', this.swtich1);

}
 public refreshValue(value : any) : void {
this.value = value;
this.swtich1 = true
 }
showAlert2() {
swal('Added to Cart', '', 'success')
}
productSaveInCart() {
this
  .modalRef2
  .hide();
this.modalref3 = this
  .modalService
  .show(this.templated);

}
selectedslot(value) {
this
  .modalref3
  .hide();
this.showAlert2();
this
.child
 .sendvalues();
this
 .child
.sendvalues();

} 
}
```

here is the parent component HTML

```
    <div fxLayout="column wrap" fxLayout.gt-md="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="center">
  <mat-card *ngFor="let product of products$ ">
    <img mat-card-image [src]="product.i.t || '../../assets/images/noimage.png'" [alt]="product.i.i">
    <mat-card-footer class="row">


      <button type="button" class="col-sm-7   matbuton2 align-self-start" mat-button>
        {{product.i.i}}
      </button>

      <button type="button" class="col-sm-2 offset-md-4 matbuton align-self-end " mat-button>
        ₹{{product.opr}}/kg
      </button>

      <fa class="col-sm-2" [name]="'cart-plus'" (click)="addcart(product,template,template2,template3)" [size]=2></fa>




    </mat-card-footer>
  </mat-card>
</div>

<ng-template #template>
  <div class="modal-header">
         <h4 class="modal-title pull-left"></h4>
    <button type="button" class="close btn pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="modalRef2.hide()">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <mat-card style="margin: 0; ">
      <img height="400px" style="width: 110%" mat-card-image [src]="modaldata.i.t || '../../assets/images/noimage.png'">
      <mat-card-footer class="row">

        <h4>Extra prep. time: 1hr</h4>

        <ng-select [allowClear]="true" [items]="items" [disabled]="disabled" (data)="refreshValue($event)" (selected)="selected($event)"
          (removed)="removed($event)" (typed)="typed($event)" placeholder="No Date selcted">
        </ng-select>
        <div *ngFor="let item of list ">
          <h4 class="col">{{item.n}}</h4>
          <app-dropdowns #child class="col" [listdata]="item"></app-dropdowns>
        </div>
        <button  (click)="productSaveInCart()" type="button" class="col  matbuton " mat-button>
          ADD to Cart
        </button>
      </mat-card-footer>
    </mat-card>
  </div>

</ng-template>

<ng-template #template2>
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-header" style="width: 30px">
          <h2 class="modal-title pull-left"></h2>
      <fa class="col " [name]="'spinner'" [spin]="true" (click)="addcart(product,template,template2)" [size]=3></fa>
    </div>
  </div>




</ng-template>
<ng-template #template3>
  <div class="modal-header">
       <h4 class="modal-title pull-left"></h4>
    <button type="button" class="close btn pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="modalRef2.hide()">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <mat-card style="margin: 0; ">


        <ng-select [allowClear]="true" [items]="slotitems" [disabled]="disabled" (data)="refreshValue($event)" (selected)="selectedslot($event)"
          (removed)="removed($event)" (typed)="typed($event)" placeholder="No Date selcted">
        </ng-select>


    </mat-card>




</div>
</ng-template>


And here is the Child component 

     import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
     import {MatProgressBarModule} from '@angular/material';

      @Component({selector: 'app-dropdowns', templateUrl: 
     './dropdowns.component.html', styleUrls: ['./dropdowns.component.scss']})
      export class DropdownsComponent implements OnInit {
      @Input()listdata : any;
      list : any
      constructor() {}
      private value : any = {};
      public items : Array < string > = [];
       ngOnInit() {

       this.list = this.listdata.op
       this
      .list
      .map(data => {
        if (data.pd == 0) {
          this
            .items
            .push(data.n);
          return data.n
        } else {
          this
            .items
            .push(data.n + '  ₹' + data.pd);
          return data.n + '  ₹' + data.pd;
        }
      });
      console.log("Listdata", this.list);
      this.value.text = 'asdgjasgd'

     }

     private _disabledV : string = '0';
     private disabled : boolean = false;

     private get disabledV() : string {return this._disabledV;}

     private set disabledV(value : string) {
      this._disabledV = value;
       this.disabled = this._disabledV === '1';
      }

      public selected(value : any) : void {
       console.log('Selected value is: ', value);
      }

      public removed(value : any) : void {
     console.log('Removed value is: ', value);
     }

     public typed(value : any) : void {
     console.log('New search input: ', value);
     }

     public refreshValue(value : any) : void {
    this.value = value;
    }
    public sendvalues() {
    console.log("HEllllllllllllllloooooooooooooooooooooooo");
    }

    }
```